# Telebot, поиск сообщения от пользователя в значениях словаря

Tags: python, telebot

Я пытаюсь по введенному сообщению пользователя совершить проверку есть ли значение в словаре (условие elif). По ключу например (Условие if) проверяет и выполняет алгоритм отлично, но по значению почему-то игнорирует.

```
dict = {'one':["один","ein"], "two":["два","zwei"]}

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def message_reply(message):
    if message.text in dict:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Я нашел перевод на русском и немецком.")
    elif message.text in dict.values():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я нашел перевод на английском.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "К сожалению перевода нет.")
```

Подскажите где может быть ошибка?

Comment: а в чем заключается смысл elif? я просто немного не понимю, ведь мы даем слово на английском, а для переводом с английского, уже стоит первый if

Answer (score 0):

у вас выходит `message.text in [['один', 'ein'], ['два', 'zwei']]`. message.text сравнивается с `['один', 'ein']`, на следущей интеракций c `['два', 'zwei']`. А вам надо `message.text in ["один", "ein", "два", "zwei"]`

```
elif message.text in [y for x in dict.values() for y in x]:
```

я бы на вашем месте структуру данных поменял бы

```
[{'en': 'one', 'ru': 'один', 'ge': 'ein'}, {'en': "two", 'ru': 'два', 'ge': 'zwei'}]
```

или

```
[['one', 'один', 'ein'], ["two", 'два', 'zwei']]
```

Comment: а почему бы сразу не: words = { "один": {"en": "one", "ge": "ein"} } ?

Comment: Пример вероятно неудачный у меня, суть в том что мне нужно осуществить поиск значений из массива значений в словаре. Как бы вы предложили изменить словарь если бы он состоял например из dict = {"Московская область": ["Балашиха", "Подольск", "Мытищи"], "Свердловская область":[Каменск-Уральский, "Нижний Тагил"]} Если бы по введенному городу мне пришлось определять область?

Comment: Но почему сразу пример не удачный. Может дело в вопросе?